# What does "Run as Java Application" do in Maven projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I've just started using Maven in Eclipse by m2e.
In many tutorials it said that I have to use "Run as Maven build" with different goals(compile, test, install) to compile and execute my application. But I noticed that "Run as Java Application" works fine too, it compiles all classes and executes the main method that I chose. Also when I use Build > Build Project it compiles all classes without "Maven Build".

So my questions are what does "Run as Java Application" do in Maven Projects, and what are differences between "Run as Maven build" with goal "compile"  and just clicking Project > Build Project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Run as Java Application** - We can run any Java application/project using this option. It doesn't matter whether project is Maven or Ant or Gradle. It should work if we have **main** method in a class.

**Run as Maven build** - this option is to build our Maven project.

**Project->Build Project** - by default Eclipse will have it's own builders. Using this option will use those builders to build the project. We can add our own builders as. Check this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_build_project.htm